# Add custom-made icons to MS Excel's and Word's repository of icons for macros

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

In MS Office (here: Excel and Word 2010) one can assign icons to VBA procedures that then appear in the menu bar (ribbon).

This can be done via "Customize the Ribbon", concretely: File --> Options --> Keyboard Shortcuts --> Macros -->  Add --> Rename.

There is a set of about 150 (roughly) predefined icons:

[image: Excel macro icons by default collection]

I want to make my own, custom-made icons. How can I do that?

Note that I am pretty sure that this cannot be made with the usual on-board methods of MS Office (then it would rather be a question for "Superuser"). I expect that this would need programming on some level of the system. Would be fine if VBA is sufficient, but possibly it is not, and I would have to go to other levels of the system.

---

PS:

Here is [something](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=21103) that Microsoft has published related to the question. It is a .docx that on opening displays in backstage view (Menu: File) all icons used anywhere in the current system (or so). This is obviously related to building one's own ribbon elements using XML. This could perhaps be a way to go...

Comment: I had the exact same question several years ago and found the answer through many hours of  google-fu and experimentation. What level of this question are you on? There are several depths.

Comment: @Jeeped If I had a concrete idea how to approach this, I would have mentioned it in the question. At the moment I am just at the (probably naive) level of hoping that somewhere there is a folder (or a file) that contains these icons, and I could add something to them. I have a pretty big reference book called "Programming Word" where I should try to find a hint, but the book is at my other place at the moment, and so I cannot check if I find something mentioned there. What would you recommend?

Comment: Do you want to customize the ribbon for every file, or for a single file? For a single file I suggest to use the Custom UI tool that you can find here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm. The site includes lots of examples on how to customize the ribbon with this tool and you can use your own icons.

Comment: @AlexdeJong   I want to customize this for (my) Excel in general, not only for a single file. - The VBA procedures that I want to call by those icons are for use in whatever Excel file is open. (Or in Word, respectivel.)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/985904/how-to-change-the-icons-in-excel-quick-access-toolbar In the link it says you can't but you never know ...

Comment: @Storax   This thread in Superuser shows only what I anyway outlined in the question as the standard procedure. What I am asking here is: does anybody have a suggestion how to overcome this restricting by any form of programming.

Comment: Yes I know but it is also said there that it is not possible to do that. So my answer would be: You just can't!
But again maybe there is someone out there with more wits than me (and surely there are a lot) who knows some cool stuff to overcome this restriction.

Comment: This is an excellent question and right on point for this forum. I don't think it's possible to modify the list as it's internal to Excel. I assume you can put your own icon on the ribbon. Awaiting @Jeeped

Comment: This might answer your question https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win009.htm

Comment: @D_Bester  Yes, indeed, on first glance rondebruin's instructions and examples look very promising. I need to study this in detail and try it. I will report here on my experience (and possibly solution).

Comment: @user4039065 I just gave you +1 for "google-fu"